# Trouble using case_when in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

It's late and I must be making a stupid mistake, but why does this usage of `case_when` generate an error?

```
x <- 1:5
dplyr:::case_when(
    x == 1 ~ TRUE,
    x != 1 ~ print(x))
#> [1] 1 2 3 4 5
#> Error: must be a logical vector, not an integer vector
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is because `case_when` expects all `RHS` to evaluate to the same type.

Here, in OP's attempt `TRUE` is of class `"logical"` and `x` is of type `"integer"` hence, it returns the error. You could try,

```
x <- 1:5
dplyr::case_when(x == 1 ~ NA_integer_, x != 1 ~ x)
#[1] NA  2  3  4  5
```

Or another way :

```
dplyr::case_when(x != 1 ~ x, TRUE ~ NA_integer_)
```